# Darwin Streaming Server Log Format?

Tags: darwin

I am writing a program that will parse and manipulate logs from Darwin Streaming Servers. Where can I get a definition of what the individual fields headers mean? Are there some kind of documentation in the DSS doc files?

For example, I have this as the log output header:

> c-ip  date    time    c-dns   cs-uri-stem c-starttime x-duration  c-rate  c-status    c-playerid  c-playerversion c-playerlanguage    cs(User-Agent)  c-os    c-osversion c-cpu   filelength  filesize    avgbandwidth    protocol    transport   audiocodec  videocodec  sc-bytes    cs-bytes    c-bytes s-pkts-sent c-pkts-received c-pkts-lost-client  c-buffercount   c-totalbuffertime   c-quality   s-ip    s-dns   s-totalclients  s-cpu-util  cs-uri-query    c-username  sc(Realm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get some information about the log format from the net, but this is not complete. Is there a link to the complete log format?

[DSS Log Format (Google Docs)](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tB6om3xWQUHIQSQH8N6CIoA&single=true&gid=0&output=html)

Answer (score 2):

Please check:

QuickTime Streaming Server 2.0 Access Log Format

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26756?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: please dont just link a website, copy the contents, and keep the link for reference. this way even if the link dies, the information stays.